# JDBC Multiple Batch Execution Issue

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

Following code tries to execute 3 Batch inserts. Second batch's second statement is wrong intentionally (INSERTD). When I run this program, then 1st and 3rd batch should be executed and data should be inserted into the database.

But it is not inserting data. Can someone tell why ? And how can I fix so that correct batch should be executed irrespective of other batch.

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {

        ArrayList<String> finalsql1 = new ArrayList<String>();
        finalsql1.add("INSERT INTO M_TEST VALUES('PUJAN1','WRL')");
        finalsql1.add("INSERT INTO M_TEST VALUES('PUJAN2','WRL')");

        ArrayList<String> finalsql2 = new ArrayList<String>();
        finalsql1.add("INSERT INTO M_TEST VALUES('PUJAN1','WRL')");
        finalsql1.add("INSERTD INTO M_TEST VALUES('PUJAN2','WRL')");

        ArrayList<String> finalsql3 = new ArrayList<String>();
        finalsql1.add("INSERT INTO M_TEST VALUES('PUJAN1','WRL')");
        finalsql1.add("INSERT INTO M_TEST VALUES('PUJAN2','WRL')");

        System.out.println("OP1=" + insertEntity(finalsql1));
        System.out.println("OP2=" + insertEntity(finalsql2));
        System.out.println("OP3=" + insertEntity(finalsql3));

    }

public static boolean insertEntity(ArrayList<String> finalsql) throws SQLException {
        Connection conn = null;
        Statement ps = null;
        boolean result = false;

        try {
            conn = getConnection();
            conn.setAutoCommit(false);
            ps = conn.createStatement();
            for (String sql : finalsql) {
                System.out.println("sql > " + sql);
                ps.addBatch(sql);
            }
            int[] count = ps.executeBatch();

            result = true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            conn.rollback();
            e.printStackTrace();
            result = false;
        } finally {
            conn.commit();
            ps.close();
            conn.close();
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

**Output**

OP1=true

OP2=false

OP3=true

Comment: I am calling method three times. so first batch's transaction should be succeeded isn't ?

Comment: Do you mean, that table `M_TEST` is empty???

Comment: In the 2nd and 3rd parts of `main` you are still using `finalsql1.add()` instead of `finalsql2.add()` and `finalsql3.add()` respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only a single batch of inserts with any data, and this includes the `INSERTD` hence it is rolling back. Why? Here's why:

```
ArrayList<String> finalsql2 = new ArrayList<String>();
finalsql1.add("INSERT INTO M_TEST VALUES('PUJAN1','WRL')");
finalsql1.add("INSERTD INTO M_TEST VALUES('PUJAN2','WRL')");
```

You are still adding entries to `finalsql1` here, so `finalsql2` and `finalsql2` are empty.

`finalsql1` has all the entries, including the deliberate mistake, so the whole lot is rolled back.

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of any errors that may exist in your code, you're relying on undefined behaviour: ["If one of the commands in a batch update fails to execute properly, this method throws a BatchUpdateException, and a JDBC driver may or may not continue to process the remaining commands in the batch. "](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeBatch%28%29)